# How could i display each collapsible individually? (MVC)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

A text file has a line item such as;

oranges, 0

'userData' is an array responsible for reading the lines from this text file, which are then split using 'delimiterChar' to separate 'oranges' and '0'. 0 is considered as the primary key of oranges, and therefor acts as the line items unique identifier.

'Oranges' is then displayed as the heading of a bootstrap collapsible. Now obviously, the user can add as many line items to the text file as required, therefore resulting in many collapsible's, all of which should be able to open independently of the others. However, as it stands, if i am to open only one collapsible, all of the collapsible's will open as well.

As displayed in the image as follows;

[image]

Upon clicking 'Oranges' (Or any other heading for that matter), all three collapsible's would open simultaneously.

Below is the code for the collapsible's:

```
@Model.result
        @if (Model.result == "")
        {
            foreach (String dataLine in Model.userData)
            {



                <p>
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#dataLine" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                        @dataLine.Split(Model.delimiterChar)[0]
                    </a>                    
                </p>

                <div class="collapse" id="dataLine">
                    <div class="card card-body w-25 p-3 collapsible" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.delimiterChar)[1]">
                        <!-- Collapsible content -->
                    </div>
                </div>

            }

        }
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Will you add a picture of what it looks like when you have multiple oranges?

Comment: Do you mean that if 'Banana' and 'Grape' were to be replaced with 'Oranges'? If that were to be the case, the same would happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code below, we added a counter variable `count` which we append to the ID of the collapsible and href target of the collapsible trigger.

```
@Model.result
   @if (Model.result == "")
   {
      int count = 0;

      foreach (String dataLine in Model.userData)
      {
         string countString = count.ToString();
         string target = "dataLine"+countString;
         string trigger = "#"+target;

         <p>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="@trigger" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
               @dataLine.Split(Model.delimiterChar)[0]
            </a>                    
         </p>

         <div class="collapse" id="@target">
            <div class="card card-body w-25 p-3 collapsible" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.delimiterChar)[1]">
               <!-- Collapsible content -->
            </div>
         </div>

         count++;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Or `@for (int i = 0; i < Model.userData.Count(); i++)` and then `dataLine@i`

Comment: I am not entirely sure if i am missing something, however by trying to append with the '@' symbol, nothing happens? Its simply viewing "dataLine@count" as a single identifier?

Comment: @SeventhWarhawk I updated the answer. Not sure why it's not parsing correctly on your end, in the updated answer, we assigned the complete target/trigger ids to another variable

Comment: This unfortunately is still showing all the collapsible's at once, i have tried the code you have suggested, directly within my program. I am unsure as to why this is the case

Comment: This throws a compilation error saying, "  CS1525: Invalid expression term ';'  ", and if i am to remove the semi-colon, it would then say, "  CS1525: Invalid expression term '}'  "

Comment: @SeventhWarhawk apologies, I updated the answer, the variable assignments must be placed inside the foreach loop.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for sticking around and helping me sir. Really cannot express my appreciation enough. Cheers!